# unsupported version of Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to import the tutorials app to Android Studio, I get this message:

`Error:The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle`

I am using android Studio 1.0.1

Please tell me the exact solution.

i change the  gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

but it doesn't work

and i also change build.gradle file in the root folder

```
dependencies {
     classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0"
}`
```

but doesn't work ...please some one help me

Comment: Can you please provide more details to your question to add more clarity?

Comment: Tried using a gradle wrapper instead ?

Comment: What is "the tutorials app"?

Comment: Upgrade to Gradle `2.5` and android plugin `1.2.3`.

Comment: And Android Studio 1.2.x